# External USB Hard drive detected but not assigned a drive letter

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, sata

I have a USB HD connected using SATA to USB connection to the a PC with XP, before it used to be recognised fine and assigned a drive letter but since some malware issues with my PC, I had to repair the XP installation, the hard drive is not being assigned a drive letter so I can't access it.
It is detected as USB mass storage however and I have looked in Hard drives in computer managment too.
I have also connected the hard drive to another PC and it is accessible.

Comment: Could be a power issue, it gets enough power to be detected but not enough to power the hdd.

Comment: Ok, currently I have SATA to usb adapter which uses mains power and since it works on the laptop, I assume there is enough power?

Comment: If it has an external power source my suggestion is not likely to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

This happens if the OS is trying to assign it a letter which is taken. Go into Computer Manager and see if you've got the drive without the letter. Then, reassign the letters how you wish.

This happens quite a lot to me when I use a dozen memory sticks in various combinations.

Comment: I thought the same but as mentioned in my post, the drive doesn't show up there either.